# Why is my timezone datetime wrong?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I use this code to format my time but the time that comes out is 5 hours wrong. I should be 06 something in calcutta now and it formats the time now as 01... something. What is wrong with the code?

```
def datetimeformat_viewad(to_format, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):
    tzinfo = timezone(timezoneinfo)
    month = MONTHS[to_format.month - 1]

    input = pytz.timezone(timezoneinfo).localize(
        datetime(int(to_format.year), int(to_format.month), int(to_format.day), int(to_format.hour), int(to_format.minute)))

    date_str = '{0} {1}'.format(input.day, _(month))
    time_str = format_time(input, 'H:mm', tzinfo=tzinfo, locale=locale)
    return "{0} {1}".format(date_str, time_str)
```

- Update

This code worked which was according to the answer below.

```
def datetimeformat_viewad(to_format, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):
    import datetime as DT
    import pytz
    utc = pytz.utc
    to_format = DT.datetime(int(to_format.year), int(to_format.month), int(to_format.day), int(to_format.hour), int(to_format.minute))
    utc_date = utc.localize(to_format)
    tzone = pytz.timezone(timezoneinfo)
    tzone_date = utc_date.astimezone(tzone)
    month = MONTHS[int(tzone_date.month) - 1]
    time_str = format_time(tzone_date, 'H:mm')
    date_str = '{0} {1}'.format(tzone_date.day, _(month))
    return "{0} {1}".format(date_str, time_str)
```

Comment: unrelated design hint: separate I/O from computations i.e., you should create 3 functions instead: 1. parse input string into `datetime` object 2. localize it in a given timezone 3. format output

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you for the comment. I'm going to refactor the code acccording to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `to_format` is a naive datetime in UTC time.
You want to *convert* it to Calcutta time.

To do this, you *localize* `to_format` to UTC time<sup>1</sup>, and then use `astimezone` to *convert* that timezone-aware time to Calcutta time:

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc
to_format = DT.datetime(2015,7,17,1,0)
print(to_format)
# 2015-07-17 01:00:00

utc_date = utc.localize(to_format)
print(utc_date)
# 2015-07-17 01:00:00+00:00

timezoneinfo = 'Asia/Calcutta'
tzone = pytz.timezone(timezoneinfo)
tzone_date = utc_date.astimezone(tzone)
print(tzone_date)
# 2015-07-17 06:30:00+05:30
```

<sup>1</sup>The `tzone.localize` method does not convert between timezones. It
*interprets* the given localtime as one given in `tzone`. So if `to_format` is
meant to be interpreted as a UTC time, then use `utc.localize` to convert the
naive datetime to a timezone-aware UTC time.

Comment: note: `pytz.utc` is a special case: you could pass it directly to `datetime` constructor (or `.replace()`) method.